# Accessing a singleton service from a form validator function

Tags: angular

I have a simple form validator function.

```
static required(control: FormControl) {
if (control.value == null || control.value.length <= 0)
        return {'required': false, 'errorMsg': 'Value is required'}
    return null
}
```

I would like to change it so it is not returning a hardcoded `errorMsg` but a localized message. The problem is that it refuses to work with my localization service which is called `LocaleService`.

The service has a single prop called `locale`. It's a JSON object containing all the localized messages. In components it's pretty easy to use: I just create a private instance in the constructor, and there it goes, it's accessible.

But the validator class doesn't want that. For starters, if I try to do this:

```
import {LocaleService} from '../services/locale.service';
export class FormValidators {

    constructor(private _localeService: LocaleService) {}

    static required(control: FormControl) {
        if (control.value == null || control.value.length <= 0)
            return {'required': false, 'errorMsg': 'Value required'}
        return null
    }
}
```

the entire thing immediately breaks and won't even build. The error message is:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for FormValidators: (?).
```

I tried to create an instance of `LocaleService` inside the static function, but it doesn't allow that. It also doesn't allow to pass it as a parameter or get it from a global variable. It is always an error.

So how can I get this function to talk with the service?

Comment: is your LocaleService `@Injectable`?

Comment: Yes, it's @Injectable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. A singleton service, as a provider, should only be defined in the `[providers]` part of `app.module.ts`. My mistake was to add it also to my `AppComponent`, and this caused the DI to create new instances in services, but not in child components.